# Fixing the intercept in statsmodels ols

Tags: statsmodels

In Python's `statsmodels.formula.api`, the ols functionality automatically includes and estimates an intercept:

```
results = sm.ols(formula="s ~ x + y + z", data=somedata).fit()
results.params
(* Intercept 0.632646, x -1.258761, y 0.465076, z 0.497991 *)
```

Because I'm using it in a linear probability model, is there any way to fix the intercept to 0.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reproduce this behavior in 2 steps:

1. Subtract the `predefined_intercept` from your targets
2. Fit OLS without intercept: include "-1" in your formula

Minimal example:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_samples = 100
predefined_intercept = 0.5

somedata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((n_samples, 3)), columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'])
somedata['s'] = somedata['x'] - 2 * somedata['y'] + 5 * somedata['z'] - predefined_intercept

results = ols(formula="s ~ x + y + z - 1", data=somedata).fit()
print(results.params)
```

Output:

```
x    0.671561
y   -2.315076
z    4.759542
```

See an official [example notebook on formulas](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html) for detailed explanations and more.